# Yii: удаление реляционных записей из БД

Tags: php, yii, mysql

Есть некая запись в БД.
При её удаление нужно удалить все что с ней связанно, и то что связанно с тем что связанно и т.д. и т.п.

Как в контексте Yii реализовать удаление реляционных записей произвольной вложенности?
Возложить это на MySql не получиться, т.к. записи распиханы по разным БД.

**UPDATE**
Кончилось место для комментов.

[[@dekameron](/users/13096/dekameron)](/users/13096/dekameron):

> @kness, так ведь до начала разработки проектируется база. Если там все осмыслено, выставлены все индексы и внешние ключи, то в 90% случаев о подобном удалении даже думать не приходится

Так случилось, что весь проект достался в наследство в крайне плохом состоянии и та часть БД которая без индексов, к сожаление активно используется из-вне, что несколько затрудняет манипуляции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить в родительскую модель функцию:

```
public function deleteRecursive($relations = array())
{
    foreach($relations as $relation) 
    {
        if(!empty($this->$relation))//(c)zenith
        {
            foreach($this->$relation as $relation_item)
            {
                $relation_item->deleteRecursive();
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            $this->$relation->deleteRecursive();
        }
    }
    $this->delete();
}
```

Затем ее вызывать parent::deleteRecursive.

Более простой способ - прописать в after(before)Delete удаление зависимостей. Так больше контроля

Comment: @knes Можно про последнее поподробней?

Comment: @knes у вас ошибка в логике  

    if(is_array($this->$relation)) //всегда TRUE

так более правильно  

    if(!empty($this->$relation))

Comment: у модели есть событие afterDelete и beforeDelete.
В них можно прописать любое действие. В том числе, удаление по рилэйшенам.

$this->children_rel->delete();

Comment: @knes имеется ввиду вручную прописать? Выглядит реально просто(для пары-тройки моделей)

Comment: да, просто вручную для всех необходимых моделей. Тогда вам не надо будет думать что еще функция, описанная выше, затрет при удалении аватарки: вы это будете знать наверняка.

Если таких очень много, придется все-таки модифицировать родительский класс.

Comment: А если просто добавлять индексы и внешние ключи в БД задавая ON DELETE CASCADE?

Пока удаление "вручную" через beforeDelete() приходилось использовать только для физического удаления файлов, связаных с моделью

Comment: on delete cascade хорошая штука, если уже все отлажено и работает идеально. В противном случае может натворить немало дел.

Comment: Я нашёл джедайское решение. Переопределил(как вы и сказали) родительский класс CActiveRecord в CActiveRecordExtended и там задал afterDelete, в котором по циклу удаляю каждую связанную запись. Теперь решаю думаю что делать при удалении 100500+ млн связанных записей. Если что-то подскадите в этом направлении, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: @kness, так ведь до начала разработки проектируется база. Если там все осмыслено, выставлены все индексы и внешние ключи, то в 90% случаев о подобном удалении даже думать не приходится

Comment: Да. Если проект пишется с 0 до 100% и после чего консервируется. 
Если проект живой, постоянно появляется что-то новое.